# Is it OK to check indirectly in a Bash if statement for exit codes if they are multiple?

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a Bash script that goes like this:

```bash
  qSHOWROOTS; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ncxy 0 "$vpos_l"; prin…
  elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    ncxy 0 "$vpos_l"; prin…
  elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
    ncxy 0 "$vpos_l"; prin…
  fi
```

`qSHOWROOTS` should only run once, non-zero exit* codes aren't bad though, so I thought it would be more appropriate to write it like shown above, but `shellcheck` is in a full panic telling me that [I should only do `if cmd;`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2181) instead, but that would limit me to either checking if exit is `0` or anywhere in `1`-`255`, correct? Can I ignore it or should I find another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that *every* command (including the test condition itself) changes `$?`. The correct method is to assign the important exit code to a variable *immediately* after the command. `qSHOWROOTS; res="${?}";`. After that, you can test `"${res}"` as many times as you like. (A `case` statement may be clearer than a succession of `if` ones.)

Comment: "in full panic"? It even marks it as a style issue!

Answer (score 13):

`$?` expands to the exit status of the last command, so in:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ncxy 0 "$vpos_l"; prin…
  elif [ $? -eq 1 ]
```

Upon running the second `[` command (assuming the first `[` failed), you'll just check the exit status of the first `[` which will be 1.

Here, it calls for a `case` statement:

```
qSHOWROOTS
case $? in
  (1) something;;
  (2) something else;;
  ...
  (*) anything else
esac
```

Where `$?` is expanded only once.

If you had to use an `if` statement, you'd need to store the exit status of `qSHOWROOTS` in a separate variable:

```
qSHOWROOTS; ret=$?
if [ "$ret" -eq 1 ]; then
  something
elif [ "$ret" -eq 2 ]; then
  something else
...
else
  anything else
fi
```

shellcheck objects to `[ $? -eq 0 ]` that you sometimes see in:

```
cmd
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

on *style* ground.

That's running the `[` command so it returns true if the previous command returned true and check that `[`'s success instead of the success of `cmd` directly which is a bit silly. You'd write: `if cmd; then`... instead.

Current versions of shellcheck don't report the missing quotes around `$?` even though that's bad coding practice and a bug as that code then only works correctly in contexts where `$IFS` doesn't contain digits.

It should be `[ "$?" -eq 0 ]` to prevent split+glob as we're in list context here in the arguments of a command (`[`). In `case $?`, we're not in list context, so the quotes are not necessary, but wouldn't harm. `case "$?"` would also work.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `qSHOWROOTS; showroots_rc=$?` even in the `case` situation -- often one of your conditions will call for printing an error message that describes what went wrong. Also, putting the collection on the same line as the command generating the exit status being collected reduces footgun availability: someone adding more log lines can't change `$?` by accident.